# How to get location (latitude and longitude) using SIM7600 GSM module without the help of GPS?

Tags: gps, gsm, gprs

i am using SIM7600G GSM module to get the location information without using GPS in it. Anyone know about how to find the location from GPRS SIM itself?!

Answer (score 0):

If such information could have been obtained from a device it wouldn't be the SIM but the GSM hardware. What you can hope to get is the cell ID of the serving cell, typically using AT commands, but this is not always true for all devices.

Depending on your country, you can find the position (longitude, latitude) of the site bearing that cell (there exist some databases). Depending on site location, urban zone or rural zone, you can approximate the position of the device within the coverage area of the cell from some hundreds meters (urban) to few tens of kilometers (rural zone where the network is usually much less dense), the theoretical maximum being 35Km...

The only way to have a precise position is by using the GPS

Comment: Not strictly a complete answer.
The location of the SIM can be derived approximately if it can talk to 3 cell towers. The network can compare signal strengths and maybe use other techniques to triangulate its location.
However to the best of my knowledge no modems can 'automatically' go and retrieve this information from the service provider. Of course if that provider made the info available through a web page or something you could fetch it there. But if such a facility can be provided anywhere it is certainly a paid extra.